# alarm dialog for turn on wifi

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-wifi

I am new in android programming. I searched on the internet but i can't find any solution, maybe for this i have not good english. anyway. When user clicked on the web link i want to show an alarm dialog to user that turn on wifi, and then user clicked on the OK button, wifi settings is shows.

This is my TextView with link:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sitename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/site2"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@id/address"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/site"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:autoLink="web"/>
```

and i set text of web with strings.xml.

sorry if my question was duplicated and sorry for my poor english.
Cheers.

EDIT: Contact.java:

```
public class Contact extends Fragment {

public String fonts="Tahoma.TTF";
Typeface face;

TextView siteName;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
            siteName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sitename);
    siteName.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    return view;
}

private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.sitename:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialog.setTitle("Turn on WI-Fi..");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to wifi settings?");
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

            break;
        }
    }

};
 }
```

Comment: I see you have a cancle button... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on button click:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to wifi settings?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // Activity transfer to wifi settings
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                    }
                });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but i add this code to my program, but when i clicked on the web name, the program shows browser and try open the site! I test my program to Emulator. Why?

Comment: I Edit my question and add my code to my question. Pleae read and say to me what is my problem !

Comment: At first remove `android:autoLink="web"`, then get the link from texview and pass it to browser intent.

Comment: Thanks. this is worked. but when i remove autoLink of xml file, the text not shows blue like URL. How can i fix it? Do i set color of text to blue? what is blue number of this? Sorry for many questions! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `onClick` of `Button`

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

This will redirect the user directly to the wifi settings screen

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```